# How to set up documentation snippets in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-studio, formatting

I'm using Eclipse Neon with C++ developer tools installed. Normally I work on Visual Studio + Visual Assist Plugin. Visual Assist has a feature called snippets, which I use to bind a shortcut key to "document a method", which essentially just applies a documentation header template to the top of the function I had selected. Example:

```
void MyTestFunction();
```

No documentation block on this. I can put my caret on `MyTestFunction` and execute my shortcut key, and it will insert a documentation block above it (I define this myself):

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void MyTestFunction();
```

I can then fill in documentation using doxygen-style syntax.

I have read a few posts on SO and elsewhere on templates, enabling doxygen support, etc. But I have yet to find something that will allow me to use a shortcut key to add documentation like this OR some type of auto-complete behavior like inserting 3 slashes (`///`) and pressing ENTER to insert the block above.

Can someone help me figure out a way to do this in Eclipse in a way that is similar to the Visual Studio + Visual Assist method?

Comment: You can refer to this thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033190/autogenerate-function-comments-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of Doxygen setup manuals for Eclipse.
You can refer to this manual: [Doxygen+Graphviz setup in Eclipse](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2012/06/25/5-best-eclipse-plugins-1-eclox-with-doxygen-graphviz-and-mscgen/)

Briefly your steps are:

1. Install Eclipse plugin: [Eclox](http://anb0s.github.io/eclox/)
2. Activate Doxygen documentation tool here: *Window->Preferences->C/C++->Editor->Documentation tool* (you may have to activate advanced view of Eclipse preferences)

After that you can type `/**` above any function and hit `Enter`